# in switch case if we write "default" as any word or single letter it does not throw an error

Tags: c#, switch-statement

In a `switch`, if we write any word or single letter instead of `default`  it does not throw an error.
e.g.

```
switch(10)
{
    case 1:
    break;

    hello:
    break;
}
```

It runs without throwing an error.

Can anyone explain how this works?

Comment: Reminds me of an old joke/trick:  C-style languages understand URLs!  You can just paste `http://www.google.com/` anywhere on its own line!  =P

Answer (score 16):

It is compiling because `hello:` is a label and thus can be the destination of a `goto`. When I compiled this I got warnings about an unreferenced label (since I did not have a goto)

Here is an example you could throw in LINQPad - you will notice that it prints both "1" and "hello":

```
switch(1)
{
    case 1:
        "1".Dump();
        goto hello;
    break;

    hello:
        "hello".Dump();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

It's unrelated to the `switch` statement.  It's a label identifier for the (rarely-used due to being bad practice) [`goto` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx).

```
goto something2;
something1:
    Console.WriteLine("world");
    goto done;
something2:
    Console.WriteLine("hello");
goto something1;
done:
```

Answer (score 5):

For your example you can see the following code snippet:

```
switch (10)
{
    case 1:
        break;

    hello:
        Console.Write("In hello label");
        break;
    case 2:
        goto hello;
        break;
}
```

In the above you are defining a label for goto statement in switch statement. If  switch statement falls to `case 2`, then it will go the label `hello`. Since your original code snippet doesn't have a `goto hello;` you will get warning of an unreferenced label.

Your label `hello`  doesn't have to do anything with the switch statement (except being defined inside).